# I need a simple method of sending SMS (via Nexmo SMS Gateway) to each client at predetermined times

Tags: php, message-queue, vonage

I've already had several people recommend RabbitMQ, IronMQ, and a plethora of other message queuing systems.

The thing is - every single one of these systems just feels like massive overkill. Like employing a Cummins 6.7 Turbo Diesel for your household vacuum cleaner. It just seems so ridiculously - nearly unusably overkill.

Literally, all I need, is some form of loop persistence that queries the daily task table, grabs the execution times, cell phone number, and pregenerated message - then sends the SMS messages to each client at whatever time was specified.

Something like this (it's just pseudo code):

```
$smsout =  new SMSFly;
$smsout->db_conn($db_un, $db_pw, $db_server, $port);
$smsout->db_stmt('SELECT * FROM `messages` ORDER BY `send_time` ASC');

$smsout->execution_time_col('send_time','H:i:s');

$smsout->execute('sendSMS');


function sendSMS($to, $message){

    $basic  = new \Nexmo\Client\Credentials\Basic(__APIKEY__, __APISECRET__);
    $client = new \Nexmo\Client($basic);

    $message = $client->message()->send([
    'to' => $to,
    'from' => 'Meeting Reminder',
    'text' => $message
    ]);
}
```

Comment: simple cron job would work

Comment: Ya, I had considered that. The reasons I'm leaning away from using cron are:
a) If the site gets busy (which is a highly probable concern) cron jobs are going to donk out. I need to be able to spawn workers.
b) if I were to spawn a new cron job per job instead of having a cron job spawn processes to send the messages, I'm going to hit a very weird wall. Cron tends to get pretty weird when it comes to time-zones.

Comment: Even locally, breaking down a date and time into a cron job that actually runs on that exact date and time is tricky business - at least for me. But there is still the issue of having cron jobs running all over the place - which just seems risky to me. I've read a few bad experienced with such systems.

Comment: one cron job checking the db every X minutes to decide to send a sms or not, i dont really understand your objections to it.

Comment: I mean - I guess I can try it - if there's really nothing out there that is as light as I'd like. But I just hear so many horror stories with cron being used in production like this.

Comment: i have use cron in production to send many thousands of invoices every day for many years.

Comment: alright - fugget - I'll give it a shot.